# Business Central 22 http requests don't show on fiddler

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-al, businesscentral, fiddler-everywhere

I'm trying to use fiddler to see the webrequests we are doing within BC. Unfortunately, it seems that fiddler isn't finding these requests that we make to external services. Has anyone tried anything like this before?

Already tried this and no results https://bizzbrainblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/27/use-fiddler-with-nav/

Comment: Also at the Network dev-tools tab doesn't show any request to fetch data.

Comment: I tried the same yesterday. The "data" transfer happen via a websocket connection, and that why you can't see it. However it looks a bit like it's a Blazer app that sends DOM updates instead of real "data", meaning you can't inspect the data going back and forth